# DOM loading using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can we control the loading of images, text and other elements like
http://www.morsa.in/

using javascript

Comment: What exactly do you mean.  Do you mean the way everything slides up onto the screen?

Comment: Waaaaaaaaay too vague for anyone to help you. You need way more detail.

Answer (score 1):

The website preloads the images, then displays them with a jQuery effect.

Here are some helpful links:

[Preloading Images in Javascript](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/preloading-and-the-javascript-image-object/5214317)

[Using jQuery effects](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/)

Answer (score 1):

This page uses jQuery with animation/easing.  Is using jQuery an option since it is just a cross-browser js library?  If not, you can setup effects in purely JS it is just far more complicated.

Take a look at:

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

[Easing](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)

[jQuery Animation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)